# Spring Boot 3 Firebase Authentication

Tags: spring, spring-boot, firebase-authentication, jwt

i need to validate my jwt token in spring boot for all api calls
i need it something like this

```
            FirebaseToken decodedToken = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().verifyIdToken(idToken);
            return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(decodedToken, null, Collections.emptyList());
```

Comment: Whats your question?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.